# How can a machine learning model learn from feedback about its performance? (i.e. telling it if it was correct/incorrect in its predictions)

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, dataset

I have a machine learning model, and it predicts the labels for a previously unseen data set. If I go through and mark each generated label as correct or incorrect, how can I use this new information to tune the weights on my model? I'm not sure what the correct phrase for adding such a feedback loop into the model is called.

Comment: You can retrain the model.

Comment: If you just mean incremental training, then the term is online learning.

Comment: Online learning is kind of what I'm looking for. But the thing is I never obtain the actual labels for the predicted set. I only have "Correct" or "Incorrect" judgments on the predicted set.

Comment: I'm looking specifically for how I can use the Correct/Incorrect judgments to further tune the model, not necessarily online.